# Ls files according to a match for a character in these files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory where I have several files such as:

```
OK_file1.txt
OK_file2.txt
OK_file3.txt
OK_file4.txt
```

and within this file I have some content such as:

```
OK_file1.txt
error: 89 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***

OK_file2.txt
Job_done

OK_file3.txt
Job_done


OK_file4.txt
error: 34 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

and I would like to parse each of these files and only list those with the character : `error` in a new file called: `Jobs_error.txt`

For the exemple this file should be

```
OK_file1.txt
OK_file4.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following option of the `grep` command:

```
$ man grep
  […]
  -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```

and a redirection (`>`):

```
$ grep -l "error" OK_file*.txt > Jobs_error.txt
```